# Fsck ask for repairs during boot

Tags: raspbian, fsck

At Raspbian, there is a `/boot/cmdline.txt` file where the option `fsck.repair` can be defined.

As far as I know, the valid values are:

- yes (always repair)
- no (never repair)
- preen (default; repair if it is safe)

What I actually want is "ask/interactive mode" before a repair.

This is what I am doing at the moment:

- At the moment, I have the setting "fsck.repair=preen".
- If the system won't boot due to an error, I have to go into the emergency console.
- But when I am inside the emergency console, I cannot run `fsck`, because I am working on the mounted filesystem, and checking it while it is mounted, would damage it. Raspbian does not seem to have a real emergency mode that works "outside" the file system (e.g. in an RAM disk).
- So I have to set `fsck.repair=yes` in the emergency console, then reboot, wait for the repair, and then when the system is booted again, I set `fsck.repair` to `preen` again.

Is there anything that I can do better? Any way to make the system asking me before doing repairs?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot really set an interactive `fsck` during boot. The only options for `fsck.repair` are:

- `preen` will automatically repair problems that can be safely fixed
- `yes` will answer *yes* to all questions
- `no` will answer *no* to all questions.

Try also setting `fsck.mode` apart from `fsck.repair`:

> fsck.mode=
>
> One of `auto`, `force`, `skip`. Controls the mode of operation. The
>   default is `auto`, and ensures that file system checks are done when
>   the file system checker deems them necessary. `force` unconditionally
>   results in full file system checks. `skip` skips any file system
>   checks.

setting this to `force` should run fsck on every boot automatically (non-interactively).

Comment: Yes, I am using `fsck.mode=force` since I am kinda paranoid ;-) But is there anything I can do to make the procedure easier? It feels wrong that I have to edit the boot parameters just to enable fsck repairs, then reboot+repair and then disable the repair boot parameter again.